# How do you avoid typing the passphrase (password) of your ssh key each time, on Linux and Windows with OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, security, passwords, git-bash

(This is a repost and edit of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601213/how-do-you-avoid-typing-the-password-of-your-ssh-key-each-time-on-linux-and-win) by [xiiryo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9927519/xiiryo) originally posted and closed fairly quickly on Stack Overflow.)

I use a **passphrase**-protected ssh key (RSA). (I used to call this a *password*-protected ssh key, but that is technically inconsistent with SSH terminology.) That means that I need to type the passphrase to decipher the key before using it. This is a good security practice as a line of defense against hackers who have gained access to my machine getting access to other machines on the network.  But typing the password each time is annoying.

I noticed that on some computers, I don't need to type the passphrase of my ssh key each time I need to use it.  But on my Windows computer, as well as some Linux servers, I need to.

I use Git Bash on Windows (The previous OP used OpenSSH on Windows). Neither of us use Putty, so it is the same key as Linux. Stored in the /.shh directory.  Ideally, this would work from the shell (e.g., Git Bash on Windows, Ubuntu terminal, and PowerShell) and from within IDEs that need my password (Such as VS Code and PyCharm).

I tried using ssh-add, but it asked for my passphrase again immediately:

```s
(base) PS C:\code> ssh-add -k C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa  
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa: 
Identity added: C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa (C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa)
(base) PS C:\code> git fetch
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Is there a way to have my computers, on Windows and Linux, remember it?

Comment: Having moved this from Stack Overflow, I wonder if this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18404272/1048186 isn't a better question anyway.

Comment: "a password-protected ssh key" – The term is "passphrase". The documentation of OpenSSH consistently uses "passphrase" for a string protecting a key file, "password" for a string authenticating a user directly (i.e. not via a key file).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Edited accordingly. Yet it is because the question used the incorrect terminology that I found it in the first place, so I've tried to reflect that in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're using two incompatible Windows ports of OpenSSH – the `ssh-add` command is from Win32-OpenSSH maintained by Microsoft, while the `ssh` client invoked by Git is from Cygwin or MinGW. The two expect to find the ssh-agent socket at different locations (and I'm not sure if their socket types are compatible).

Point your `$env:GIT_SSH` environment variable to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`, or use the version of `ssh-add` that comes with Git (or point GIT_SSH to PuTTY's plink.exe which then uses Pageant).

Comment: I have a feeling that when I edited this question, I made it less clear. Personally, I use Git bash. But I imagine others may use OpenSSH. Thanks for reminding me that Git Bash does NOT use OpenSSH behind the scenes. I have a hard time keeping these details straight.

Comment: I have a feeling your answer may apply to the original question as well, though! The code snippet is verbatim from the original question.

Comment: No, that's exactly the point, "Git Bash" **does** use OpenSSH behind the scenes – but a different variant of OpenSSH than the one shipped with Windows.